# I try to count 2 string values

Tags: php

I have an array that have values: string(6) "245,56" string(6) "269,82". I Try to count them but it count 245+269 instead of 245.56+269.82.

```
<?php
$myValue="";
    foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key=>$values){
                $myValue += $values['product_price'];
           } echo $myValue;
?>
```

I expect the output of 245.56+269.82 to be 515.38, but the actual output is 514.

Comment: In computer programming `,` is not decimal separator. You need to replace that with `.`

Comment: Why are you initializing `$myValue` as string since it's supposed to be numeric ?

Comment: @Andreas good catch !

Comment: It's a bit tricky since the rest of the question refers to numbers with dots.

Comment: See [`numfmt_parse()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php)

Answer (score 2):

In computer programming `,` is not decimal separator. You need to replace that with `.`.

```
$myValue += str_replace(",", ".", $values['product_price']);
```

And why do you initiate the myValue with "" if you know it's going to be numbers in it?

Answer (score 0):

U can do with int type cast

```
$myValue +=(int)  $values['product_price'];
```